# Elasticsearch Circle Ingest Processor on Amazon Elasticsearch Service

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm trying to create an ingest pipeline using the `circle` processor that converts circles to polygons, since the `circle geo_shape` is being deprecated, following the documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/ingest-circle-processor.html#_example_circle_defined_in_geojson

However, when I run it against my Amazon Elasticsearch 7.7 instance, it gives me the following error:

```
{
   "error":{
      "processor_type":"circle",
      "reason":"No processor type exists with name [circle]",
      "root_cause":[
         {
            "processor_type":"'circle'",
            "reason":"'No processor type exists with name [circle]'",
            "suppressed":"[{'type': 'parse_exception', 'reason': 'No processor type exists with name [circle]', 'processor_type': 'circle'}]",
            "type":"'parse_exception'"
         }
      ],
      "suppressed":[
         {
            "processor_type":"'circle'",
            "reason":"'No processor type exists with name [circle]'",
            "type":"'parse_exception'"
         }
      ],
      "type":"parse_exception"
   },
   "status":400
}
```

From my understanding, the `circle` processor is available since version 7.4.

Is this a known issue? Is there a way to add this processor to AWS's Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circle processor is available only with x-pack.

x-pack doesn't come with the standard ES package, and is paid. So if you want to use the processor please buy x-pack.

Link : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/setup-xpack.html